# Getting extra cell at bottom of table

Tags: tables

I am trying to make a 4x5 table with the following code.

```
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c |}
    \hline  
    K(1,1) & K(1,2) & K(1,3) & $\cdots$ & K(1,m) \\ \hline  
    K(2,1) & K(2,2) & K(2,3) & $\cdots$ & K(2,m) \\ \hline  
    $\cdots$ & $\cdots$ & $\cdots$ & $\cdots$ & $\cdots$ \\ \hline  
    K(m,1) & K(m,2) & K(m,3) & $\cdots$ & K(m,m) \\ \hline  
    \label{Example}
\end{tabular}
```

For some reason, I get an extra cell at the bottom as shown in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

put the `\label{Example}` after `\end{tabular}` if really needed. For LaTeX it is like a contents of the first column in a new line.

```
[...]
\end{tabular}
\label{Example}
```